# How can I add songs to my wordpress site?

Tags: plugins

I would like to share some songs in my Wordpress site for listening. Could you please say some ideas or plugin which would make it easy and helpful?

There is no necessity for download option

Comment: What have you tried? Please note that *plugin recommendation* questions are off-topic for WPSE, as per our FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

In the current Version (3.7) of Wordpress it is possible to just upload mp3 files to your post and insert them, using the known media upload button. They will then render as a nice html5 player.

Answer (score 1):

The best idea could be uploading your music to [soundcloud](http://soundcloud.com) and embedding it to WordPress.

WordPress supports embedding music from SoundCloud. Refer to this: [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds), [Adding music in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/add-mp3-audio-files-wordpress/)

Also you will get a good performance in your music loading performance in using Soundcloud service instead of uploading it to your host.